# How to invoke localhost servlet with URL Connection without specifying full url?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, urlconnection

I am invoking a local servlet from a jsp, the servlet simply returns a json string:

```
URL url = new URL("http://myapp.appspot.com/myservlet");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(is, writer, "UTF-8");

String jsonStr = writer.toString();
```

Can I do this with a relative path so that it works both locally and on the deployed instance?

Comment: Are both the JSP and the servlet part of the same application?  If so, then you shouldn't be making an HTTP call to the servlet.  You should refactor your code so that the code that generates the JSON string can be accessed from the JSP.

Comment: @Michael yes it's the same app - in a standard scenario I'd go from the jsp straight to the datastore as you suggest but the servlet is being already accessed by other apps too so I'd rather not duplicate that logic. I might end up changing it for performance but I am just curious to understand if there is a way of doing this without specifying a full path :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JSTL with the tag

```
<c:import>
```

Alternatively, for your posted code, you could use

```
   String requestURL = request.getRequestURL().toString();
   String servletPath = request.getServletPath();
   String serverPath = requestURL.substring(0,requestURL.indexOf(servletPath));
   URL url = new URL(serverPath + "/myservlet");
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
String urlString = "http://localhost/myservlet/";
```

localhost is an alias for 127.0.0.1, which is always "the local computer".

ServletRequest.getServerPort() will let you know the port where the user connected.

Depending on where this is happening,  what you really might want to use is ServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher(), which bypasses the network layer, and stays inside your servlet container.

You can wrap the HttpResponse, and send that through to the RequestDispatcher, then extract the String that was produced with something like this:

```
http://goo.gl/kRW1b
```

Comment: Thanks, but don't I need to specify the port? The port in the development environment is known but I don't know how to figure out the port on the deployed app-engine instance (and if it's different then it's just like specifying a different url).

Comment: Brad I don't think using `ServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher()` would work.  The `RequestDispatcher` class only lets you forward the request to another servlet or include the response of another servlet inside the response of the calling servlet.  You can't, like, call a servlet and then get the response back as a string.

Comment: expanded suggestions on port and how to get the response from a subrequest via RequestDispatcher.